# LISP Can anyone explain me this cond example?

Tags: lisp

```
(defun Left (state)
  (setq new_place (- (second state) 1))
  (cond 
    ((endp state) NIL)
    ((= (first state) 1) NIL) 
    (T (> (second state) 1) (list skoupa (- (second state) 1)  (last state)))))
```

I cannot understand this line ((endp state) NIL) that NIL drives me crazy whats the purpose of it ? i understand endp state will result True or NIL. for example if it results True then i will have ((T) NIL) is this a correct statement? what is the result of this?

Comment: Are you sure this code works?

Comment: There are a few things, which look fishy, in the code, but I don't understand the question. Could you try to reword it?

Comment: I believe an `if` is missing in the T clause.

Comment: So yeah is this " ((T) NIL) " a vaild statement?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to convert this to pseudocode.

Added an `if` as stated in my comments assuming it was supposed to be

```
(T  (if (> (second state) 1) 
      (list skoupa (- (second state) 1)) 
      (last state)))))
```

HTH.

```
function Left (state)
  set new_place = (second state)-1
  if state is empty
    return NIL
  else
    if (first state) == 1
      return NIL
    else 
      if (second state) > 1
        return (list skoupa (second state)-1
      else 
        return (last state)
```